# Determine wrong keyboard layout and translate to the right keyboard layout with ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, typescript, algorithm, elasticsearch

I have a task about determining in what language should I translate the wrong keyboard layout input to elasticsearch.

Example:

1. `руддщ` - > `hello`.
2. `ghbdtn` -> `привет`. // Russian hello.

So if I want to write `hello` with a Russian keyboard layout, it will be `руддщ`.
The main problem is how to determine in what language should my search translate the request according to the wrong keyboard layout. Rather it could be English -> Russian. Or Arabic -> English or even English -> Chinese.

Is there any way to do it with elasticsearch or maybe npm packages or even algorithms that I can use to determine to which language should I translate the wrong keyboard layout and SHOULD I even translate that language?

In other words, there is 2 problems:

1. Determine that person wrote a word in the wrong language.
2. Determine in which language the person wrote a word.